# Django correct list using article_id

Tags: python, html, django

views.py

```
def article(request, article_id):
return render(request, 'article.html', {
    'article': Article.objects.get(id=article_id)
})
```

urls.py

```
from . import views
urlpatterns = [
    path('articles/', views.articles, name='articles'),
    path('articles/<int:article_id>/', views.article, name='article'),
]
```

article.html

```
<div class="pagination">
    <a href="#">&laquo;</a>
    <a class="active" href="/articles/{{ article.id }}/">1</a>
    <a href="/articles/{{ article.id }}/">2</a>
    <a href="#">3</a>
    <a href="#">4</a>
    <a href="#">5</a>
    <a href="#">6</a>
    <a href="#">&raquo;</a>
</div>
```

Someone can tell me how add to pagination list correct article by correct id and last and end article ID
in HTML?
Thanks a lot

Comment: could you explain more

Comment: I want in class pagination use a href’s by article.id but that: articleID_thenewelement, articleIDelement1, articleIDelement2, articleIDtheoldestelement

Comment: You've not included the view, but your `articles` view could use the `ListView` which does pagination for you; https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#listview